# change the expiry date of cookies in websphere commerce

Tags: cookies, customizing, wcs

I need to change the expiry date of OOB (out of box) cookie in websphere Commerce 7 .How can I do it ? which file in WCS has the properties for OOB Cookies ?

Answer (score 2):

wc-server.xml holds the fields you want.

```
 <PersistentSession
    cookieExpiry="-1"
    delayNewPersistentGuestSession="true"
    display="false" enable="true"/>
```